# jBPM Timer Event - "Unable to create response: There is no start node that matches the trigger none"

Tags: jbpm

Hi I'm new to jBPM and I want to know what and how a timer event work. In order to do so I creted a simple process. When starting process instance below error was thrown,
`Unexpected error occurred: Unexpected HTTP response code when requesting URI 'http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/SecondBPMProject_1.0.0/processes/com.testspace.secondbpmproject.TimerOne/instances'! Error code: 500, message: "Unable to create response: There is no start node that matches the trigger none"`
Anyone knows why?